# Possible false security alert from Google

Tags: google

Google sent me a security alert about my account being accessed from a new device. In fact, I believe I did access my account myself from a new device but it was NOT the device Google warned me about. I used an Amazon Firestick for access and Google said it was an Asus Nexus 7. Is it possible Google's device detection program was in error?

Comment: Seems to be a problem also reported by others - see https://support.google.com/mail/thread/13066579?hl=en

Comment: Google is guessing the device based on its [`User-Agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) (and possibly other details from the HTTP headers, and how the client behaves). Probably Amazon Firestick resembles Asus Nexus 7 from that perspective. The last time I got this warning from Google it contained the IP address, too. That's a more accurate piece of detail.

Comment: These as well as previous posts are both reassuring and enlightening. Now the question is: Who is at fault for this erroneous scare, Amazon or Google?  I want to know which one to bug.